# Monitor who is writing to table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sitting on an oracle database with a lot of stored procedures. I didn't write them and I can't edit them either.

I can see, that data is being written to a table, but I can't figure out what process is doing it and I'm sure, that it's an automatic process and no user is actively doing it.

I also know the procedure that is used to write the data.

Is there any way I can monitor what process that is calling the procedure? 
I assume it is an event, but I'm not sure.

BR Kresten

Comment: Do you have time stamps on the records?  You could compare the times with the concurrent request log to see if a concurrent request is calling the procedure.  Or maybe a trigger is making the call to SP..

Comment: I think what you want is [DBMS_TRACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_trace.htm#i1002104) You have to enable tracing and check sessions.

Comment: I'm not sure where I find a request log. Is it a file or a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might start with checking the DBMS_SCHEDULER to see if they're being kicked off there.

```
Select
   job_name             "Job name",
   owner                "Owner",
   decode(enabled,'TRUE','Yes','FALSE','No')            "Enabled?",
   to_char(last_start_date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')     "Last run",
   to_char(next_run_date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')       "Next date",
   program_owner        "Program owner",
   program_name         "Program name",
   job_type             "Job type",
   job_action           "Job action",
   schedule_name        "Schedule name",
   start_date           "Start date",
   repeat_interval      "Repeat interval"
from dba_scheduler_jobs order by 2, 3 desc, 4 desc;
```

Another possibility is to enable auditing on the table in question, see the following example in the Oracle docs.

[Auditing example](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4007.htm#i2116021)

And you would look at the auditing records via the dba_common_audit_trail view.

Note that auditing can have a serious performance overhead, so know how to enable it and disable it as well. You probably won't want to leave it on full-time.